# I want to retrieve text between delimiter when I match several patterns

Tags: sed

I have a file like this:

```
define service {
        host_name       MyHOST
        service_description     Uptime
        obsess_over_service     1
        low_flap_threshold      0.000000
        high_flap_threshold     0.000000
        stalking_options        n
        freshness_threshold     5
        }
define service {
        host_name       MyHOST
        service_description     Users - Memory usage
        event_handler   notify-service-by-email
        obsess_over_service     1
        low_flap_threshold      0.000000
        high_flap_threshold     0.000000
        stalking_options        n
        freshness_threshold     5
        notes_url       rrd2graph.cgi?hostname=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$
        }
define service {
        host_name       MyHOST
        service_description     Users - Nr of Processes
        event_handler   notify-service-by-email
        obsess_over_service     1
        low_flap_threshold      0.000000
        high_flap_threshold     0.000000
        stalking_options        n
        freshness_threshold     5
        notes_url       rrd2graph.cgi?hostname=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$
        }
define service {
        host_name       MyHOST
        service_description     Users - Processor usage
        event_handler   notify-service-by-email
        obsess_over_service     1
        low_flap_threshold      0.000000
        high_flap_threshold     0.000000
        stalking_options        n
        freshness_threshold     5
        notes_url       rrd2graph.cgi?hostname=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$
        }
```

and I want to retrieve the text in between { and } where I match host_name and service_description.

What I have tried but it only returns the host_name, service_description and freshness_threshold:

```
sed -n -e "/define service[[:space:]]*{/,/}/ {
                /host_name/ h
                /service_description/ H
                /freshness_threshold/G
                s/freshness_threshold.*$HOST.*service_description.*$SERVICE.*$/\0/p
        }" objects.cache
```

Comment: `sed '/define service {/{:1;/}/!{N;b1};/'"$Yourvar"'/p};d'`

Comment: Hi, I need the above to match not only one variable but both in the same time.

Comment: Put the other variable after then.

Comment: I am sorry ... but how?

Comment: Work it out, what use is me just giving you code that you don't understand and will make no effort to.

Comment: You're right. Thank you!

Comment: sed '/define service {/{:1;/}/!{N;b1};/'"$Yourvar".*"$Anothervar"'/p};d'

Comment: I would like to understand the line you provided, so would you care to explain, please? I looked into man page N,1,b1,!, made several tests, but I need some words. One more question that rose from my tests: How come using /'"$Yourvar".*"$Anothervar"'/ or /'"$Anothervar".*"$Yourvar"'/ returns the same results?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v RS="define service {|}" '/host_name *HOST/ && /service_description *SERVICE/' File
```

**Eample:**

```
awk -v RS="define service {|}" '/host_name *MyHOST/ && /service_description *Users - Memory usage/' File

        host_name       MyHOST
        service_description     Users - Memory usage
        event_handler   notify-service-by-email
        obsess_over_service     1
        low_flap_threshold      0.000000
        high_flap_threshold     0.000000
        stalking_options        n
        freshness_threshold     5
        notes_url       rrd2graph.cgi?hostname=$HOSTNAME$&service=$SERVICEDESC$
```

Comment: Hi, Works great with awk. Thank you! I will just need to understand how to use bash variables within and how to make awk to not use regular expresion when for example I am searching for something like "text [info] text". Works when manual escaped "text \[info\] text".